# How to calculate an Endpoint (E1.x E1.y) with Javascript where source, slope and distance are given?

Tags: javascript, coordinates

I need to calculate an endpoint (E1.x and E1.y) with Javascript but I cannot get it to work properly.

Given are the starting point with S1.x and S1.y coordinates, the distance d and the coordinates of a target point (T1.x and T1.y). T1 determines the direction/line/slope S1-E1 (so E1 is on the line S1-T1, sometimes between S1-T1, sometimes not).

Needed is the calculated endpoint (E1.x and E1/y) that is on a line determined by S1-T1 with a distance d (calculated from S1).

S1.y is always lower than T1.y, but S1.x is sometimes positive/higher and sometimes negative/lower than T1.x.

```
 function calculateEndPoint() {
    console.log("pressedDistance: " + pressedDistance + " sourceCoordinates " + sourceCoordinates + " actualDist: " + actualDist + " targetCoordinates " + targetCoordinates + " difference : " + difference);
   var S1 = {
     x : sourceCoordinates[0],
     y : sourceCoordinates[1],
     };

   var T1 = {
       x : targetCoordinates[0],
      y : targetCoordinates[1]
    };  

// slope
var slope = (T1.y-S1.y)/(T1.x-S1.x);
// Find angle of line
var theta = Math.atan(Math.abs(slope));
// the coordinates of the E1 Point
var E1x= Math.abs(T1.x + pressedDistance * Math.cos(theta));
var E1y= Math.abs(T1.y + pressedDistance * Math.sin(theta));
console.log("E1x: " + E1x);
console.log("E1y: " + E1y);
var calcCo = [E1x,E1y];
return calcCo;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to do it with linear arithmetic (and pythagorean distance calculation), do not involve any angles.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is illustrated and explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2109383

```
function calculateEndPoint() {
    var x = sourceCoordinates[0] - (pressedDistance *(sourceCoordinates[0]-targetCoordinates[0]))/actualDist;
    var y = sourceCoordinates[1] - (pressedDistance *(sourceCoordinates[1]-targetCoordinates[1]))/actualDist;
    console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
    var calcCo = [x,y];
    return calcCo;
}
```